# How to highlight current and previous move of the player in chessboard.js?

Tags: chessboards

I want player 2 to see what last move player 1 has moved. The best way to do this would be to highlight the last move. How is it possible in chessboard.JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't familiar with chessboard.js - but a quick search of their site turned up an example entitled [**Piece Highlight 1**](http://chessboardjs.com/examples#5004), which seems to do just that.  The link includes both javascript and HTML examples, depending on which you're looking for.

Since links are not permanent, here is the HTML example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.highlight-white {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px yellow;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px yellow;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px yellow;  
}
.highlight-black {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px blue;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px blue;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px blue;  
}
</style>
<script src="js/chess.js"></script>
<div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
```